# How to create shell that can run programs in the background in C?

Tags: c, shell, unix, command-line

I know that in the child process I have to call `setpgrp()` but I'm not sure what to do with the parent process.  I know the parent is not supposed to call `wait()` but how do I go about doing this?  I want to have a shell that runs a program in the background if the user types `&` after his/her command.

My code is below:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#define BUFFER_SIZE 1<<16
#define ARRAY_SIZE 1<<16

static void parseCmdArgs(char *buffer, char** cmdArgs, 
                size_t cmdArgsSize, size_t *nargs)
{
    char *bufCmdArgs[cmdArgsSize]; 
    char **temp;
    char *buf;
    size_t n, p;

    cmdArgs[0] = buf = bufCmdArgs[0] = buffer;  

    for(temp=bufCmdArgs; (*temp=strsep(&buf, " \n\t")) != NULL ;){
        if ((*temp != '\0') && (++temp >= &bufCmdArgs[cmdArgsSize]))
            break;
    }

    for (p=n=0; bufCmdArgs[n]!=NULL; n++){
        if(strlen(bufCmdArgs[n])>0)
            cmdArgs[p++]=bufCmdArgs[n];
    }

    *nargs=p;
    cmdArgs[p]=NULL;
}
  //int main(int argc, char *argv[], char *envp[]){
int main(void)
{
    char buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
    char *args[ARRAY_SIZE];
    int retStatus;
    size_t nargs;
    pid_t pid;

    printf("$dummyshell\n");
    while(1){

        printf("> ");
        fgets(buffer, BUFFER_SIZE, stdin);
        parseCmdArgs(buffer, args, ARRAY_SIZE, &nargs); 


        if (nargs==0)
            continue;

        if (!strcmp(args[0], "help"))
        {
            printf("cat                    cd (absolute path references only\n");
            printf("exit\n");
            printf("help                   history\n");
            printf("jobs                   kill\n");
            printf("ls                     more\n");
            printf("ps                     pwd\n");
            continue;
        }

        if (!strcmp(args[0], "exit" ))
            exit(0);


    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
      setpgrp();//Is this right?
    else if (pid > 0)
      pid = wait(&retStatus);//What do I do here?
    else {
      if (execvp(args[0], args)){
        fprintf(stderr, "%s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(127);
      }
    }

    }    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If the user adds `&`, the program will run in the background without you coding anything special.  It will go into suspend mode only if it needs keyboard input.

Comment: Background operation does not require anything special to be in the child's code… it's strictly the parent -- if the parent does not `wait()` then the child is running in the background.

Comment: Is what I have correct?  I want the shell to return a prompt immediately if the user has an & at the end of his/her command.

Comment: How much you want to mimic a real shell is up to you. If a background process tries to read from the same terminal as the shell, what do you want it to do? Fail or get a SIGTTIN signal and pause until the user decides to start it in the foreground? The UNIX programming FAQ http://www.mercymachines.net/unix/faq_toc.html has lots of good info about process control.

Comment: I guess I would let it fail.  My program is not handling the '&' at the end properly.